# How to get a total count based on distinction of two columns with PySpark?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I do a **summation** of the **frequency** based on distinct **ID & Location** in PySpark?

Feels like I need to do window partition by ID and Location and then add the frequency but not sure how to write this in Pyspark code:

**Input**

| ID | Location | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Mcd | 2 |
| AAA | Mcd | 1 |
| BBB | Nandos | 1 |
| BBB | Nandos | 3 |
| AAA | KFC | 2 |
| BBB | KFC | 4 |

**Output**

| ID | Location | Total Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Mcd | 3 |
| AAA | KFC | 2 |
| BBB | Nandos | 4 |
| BBB | KFC | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple group by and sum:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('ID', 'Location').agg(F.sum('Frequency').alias('TotalFrequency'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `GroupBy` fucntion.

```
yourInput.groupBy("ID",Location).sum("Frequency").alias("TotalFrequency").show(truncate=False)
```

**Note:** Please check link for aggregate functions in pyspark [Link of Aggregate Functions](https://hendra-herviawan.github.io/pyspark-groupby-and-aggregate-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

1st make dataframe to table then you can query from that table then you use normal query

```
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")

"select id, location, sum(Frequency) from mytable
group by id, location"
```